# Enum Class for month and keeper

Tags: java, enums

I am being asked to create a new public enum class called Month and provide it with the enum constants of January – December, and I am also asked to write a reminder letter to all keepers at the start of the month at which their tax expires and write a method in the DVLA class that will return a data structure of my choice that will hold the registration numbers, names and addresses of all keepers whose car should be retaxed at the end of the month in question.

Enum class I have so far:

```
package DVLA;

public enum Month {

    January(1),
    February(2),
    March(3),
    April(4),
    May(5),
    June(6),
    July(7),
    August(8),
    September(9),
    October(10),
    November(11),
    Decemeber(12);

    private final int value;

    private Month(int value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

and the keeper class:

```
package DVLA;

public class Keeper implements Comparable<Keeper> {

    private final RegNo regno;
    private String forename;
    private String surname;
    private Address address;

    public Keeper(RegNo regno, String forename, String surname, Address address)
    {
        this.regno = regno;
        this.forename = forename;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.address = address;
    }

    public int compareTo(Keeper kp) {
        if(kp == null)
            return -1;
        else
            return regno.compareTo(kp.regno);
    }

    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        Keeper kp = (Keeper) obj;
        if (kp == null)
            return false;
        else
            return regno.equals(kp.regno);
    }

    public String getForename() 
    {
        return forename;
    }

    public void setForename(String forename) 
    {
        this.forename = forename;
    }

    public String getSurname() 
    {
        return surname;
    }

    public void setSurname(String surname) 
    {
        this.surname = surname;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Keeper [regno=" + regno + ", forename=" + forename
                + ", surname=" + surname + ", address=" + address + "]";
    }
}
```

Comment: And your question is ?

Comment: I am been asked to a method in the DVLA class that will return a data structure of my choice that
will hold the registration numbers, names and addresses of all keepers whose car should be retaxed
at the end of the month in question.

Comment: What is the problem you're encountering?  A compiler error?  An Exception?  Something else?

Comment: the thing is that its compiling and all that but I don't know where to go from here

Comment: So do you have a class that the `Keeper` objects get added to?  What kind of structure do you store them in?  Is it a structure that you can iterate through?  And how will you tell, for each `Keeper`, whether it should be retaxed in the current month?

Comment: yep, yes it is a structure you can iterate through, that is what I cant find out, I cant tell for each whether it should be retaxed.

Answer (score 0):

> create a new public enum class called Month and provide it with the enum constants of January – December

You seem to have managed that - although I don't see why each needs a `value`. You should investigate the [ordinal()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#ordinal%28%29) method of the `Enum` class.

> and I am also asked to write a reminder letter to all keepers at the start of the month at which their tax expires

There's a problem here - your `Keeper` class does not have an expiry date for their tax disc. I would recommend you add that first.

> and write a method in the DVLA class that will return a data structure of my choice that will hold the registration numbers, names and addresses of all keepers whose car should be retaxed at the end of the month in question.

I believe once you have added the expiry date to the `Keeper` class this will become obvious.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help, i would do that now